# Request to retag "preposition" to "prepositions"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag, retag-request

According to the tagging recommendations, we should use [prepositions](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prepositions) instead of [preposition](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preposition). However, we cannot add a [prepositions](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prepositions) tag now.

> Creating the new tag [prepositions] is not allowed since the tag [preposition] already exists.

Comment: @hippietrail: I think SE asks to use also the tag in question. I was not certain however if I should include the old or the new tag.

Comment: I believe we'll need a mod to do this. Could compile a list of problem tags in the meantime.

Comment: @kotekzot Will the moderator just get all these requests eventually? I hope so.

Comment: @Alenanno Are you quite sure about what you've done with re-tagging of this post? I think I've done everything according to SE meta recommendations on retagging request, though I cannot find it now. In general may I suggest that we add comments if we do heavy editing (including tags) in meta, especially while we are in the early days of this SE.

Comment: @texnic Sure! The fact is that `support` is usually adopted when you don't understand something, at least I've seen it used like that. You're not asking for a re-tag, but rather to fix tags, they are two different things.

Comment: @Alenanno Well, as far as I understand, you should attract the support people attention, hence the support tag. You should mention the tag in question, so that they there is no ambiguity. And it's not a feature request since it's an already implemented feature of SE, we just need to use it. That's how I understand it. The problem is that I didn't invent all this, I've read it somewhere and cannot find the place any more. Can someone help?

Comment: @texnic The `feature-request` is not only for asking for new features. I've seen it used in other ways too. I'll ask other mods. :)

Comment: @Alenanno I still cannot find the guidelines I've mentiond above, however here is an example of retagging process on Stackexchange itself: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/58140/revisions Note the addition of the support tag in rev. 2.

Comment: @Alenanno (Sorry for spamming) I've found it! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/retag-request/info Please restore the support tag if you agree.

Comment: @texnic Uhm, it seems you're right. I can't rollback, can you do it? :P I'll ask the mods anyway so they can explain this to me. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I merged [preposition](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preposition) into [prepositions](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prepositions) and set up a synonym so that future uses of [preposition](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preposition) are remapped automatically.